# What does "Inversion about $C$" mean?

Tags: inversive-geometry

Let $\Delta ABC$ be a triangle with orthocenter $H$ and
altitudes $AD, BE, CF$. Perform an inversion around $C$ with radius $\sqrt{CH \cdot CF}$. Where do
the six points each go?

I'm having trouble with the wording of the statement. Does it mean inversion about the circle centered at $C$ with radius $\sqrt{CH \cdot CF}$? Rest, I can solve the matter myself.

Comment: What about [inversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611868/find-the-circle-of-inversion-that-inverts-one-given-triangle-into-another-given?rq=1)?

Comment: Yes, it does seem that the inversion about the circle centered at $C$ with radius $\sqrt{CH\cdot CF}$ maps $A$ to $E$ and vice versa, $B$ to $D$ and vice versa, and $F$ to $H$ and vice versa... I've commonly seen people omitting mention of the circle and just mentioning the centre.

Comment: Inversion around $C$ whith radius $\sqrt{CH \cdot CF}$ means that the point $X$ will be inverted in the point $X'$ such that $XC\cdot X'C=XX'^2-(\sqrt{CH \cdot CF }^2$

Comment: There is also inversion in a point $C$, which sends $X$ to $C-\vec{CX}$. In 2D, this is also a 180 rotation around $C$.